# How to prove this limit via definition?

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I would like to know how to prove this limit via the epsilon delta definition:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to3}\frac{x+1}{(x-3)^2}=\infty$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I wrote out the definition:
$\forall M>0 \exists \delta>0: 0<|x-3|<\delta \rightarrow \frac{x+1}{(x-3)^{2}}>M$

And tried solving the inequality for x. I arrived at this conclusion:
$x=-\frac{-6*M+\sqrt{16*M+1}-1}{2*M}$ but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Well if $|x-3| < \delta$ then $\frac 1{|x-3|} > \frac 1{\delta}$ and $(\frac 1{|x-3|})^k > (\frac 1{\delta})^k$.....  Just sayin'.

Comment: I realize that my goal is to find a delta such that the inequality is true. At the same time I need to find it such that the delta is as small as possible. I am however stuck.

Comment: @OP Hint: Note that $x+1>3$ when $|x-3|$ is close to $0$. In particular, for $\delta<1$, $$\frac{x+1}{(x-3)^2}>\frac3{(x-3)^2}>M$$Does that help?

Comment: You are not solving for $x$ you are solving for $\delta.$

Comment: it does, thank you @DonThousand

Answer (score 0):

$\forall M >0, \exists \delta > 0 : |x-3|<\delta \implies |\frac {x+1}{(x-3)^2}|> M$

Lets force  $\delta < 1$  which will force $x+1>2$

$|\frac {x+1}{(x-3)^2}| > \frac {2}{\delta^2} > M$

When $\delta< \min (\sqrt {\frac {2}{M}}, 1),\frac {x+1}{(x-3)^2}> M$